# How do I enable an IPv6 connection?

Tags: ios, ipv6

I submitted an app to the AppStore, but they rejected it, because it fails to connect to IPv6.  An example url from my app is:

http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json

I ran a test on this URL at [chair6.net](http://ready.chair6.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.nal.usda.gov%2Fndb%2Fsearch%2F%3Fformat%3Djson), and sure enough, the IPv6 tests failed.

I have no idea what I am doing. :)  I took a look at some [search results](https://blog.mythic-beasts.com/2014/09/15/get-your-site-ready-for-ipv6-a-step-by-step-guide/), but they suggest I have to make server-side changes.  I do not own the site, so I cannot make any changes to the server.

How can I enable IPv6 when connecting to that URL?

Comment: If you don't control the server or even the network, you cannot enable this protocol.

Comment: @closetnoc uhhh.. Any ideas what I should do? I suspect there is still a way

Comment: I know nothing about creating apps these days. As far as the server or network is concerned, IPv6 is an installed protocol stack and has nothing to do with code. This is the first I am hearing IPv6 is required. If there is no code change the negates this requirement, then in order to have IPv6, you will need access to a server or network where IPv6 is available. If you have hosting now, you may need to change providers. We have people here who write apps. I suggest waiting to see if there is something you can do other than what I am telling you. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't require the server to be reachable over IPv6 (yet). They do however require your app to work on an IPv6-only network with NAT64 and DNS64. The NAT64 service will make IPv4-only servers reachable.

They require this because more and more networks deploy this model of connectivity, and they don't want their users to have bad experiences. If you don't have a network with NAT64 available then a MacOS system can simulate one for you so you can test. The Apple developer documentation had a section on how to set that up: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html